# reducing ajax download time of a php generating a json string

Tags: php, ajax, json, apache, compression

I'm using an ajax call to download a php file producing a json string out of an sql query.

So as common, The request is for this .php and in the .php I'll do the query and echo the results as json-encoded string.

The file is about 850Kb (2500 records..), so it take a while to get it. I was searching for a way to reduce the download time. I was thinking of activating some kind of apache compression, just like css or js, but:

- don't know if it's a good idea in this case
- don't know exactly the htaccess syntax and mime type. And have I to compress a json mime or a php one?

Anyone has already solved this kind of issues?

:)

Comment: Have you tried to paginate the results?

Comment: how long is it taking? do some timing both client side and with your script so you know the response time and the time it takes to execute.  are you only printing out the data that's needed or extra stuff?  give us your timings and then provide code on where the bottle neck is happening so we can help you

Comment: Hi, I don't know too much instruments (apart from testing and firebug net) to get benchmarks but I'm quite sure the bottleneck is on download (file size). The file is a really simple query, it takes about .5s to start downloading so all the query and php processing is that .5s. The other time (20s) is after, to download the file. In fact, it's when I print out (echo) the json_encoded query results that the file gets heavy and things slow down. That's the reason for I was thinking of some kind of server-side compression.

Comment: P.s. please excuse me for not writing the code but unfortunately I'm editing it on a remote computer terminal (vim) via teamviewer, so I can't just copy-paste.. Anyway, really, it's basically a really simple select query with 1 inner join and firebug says it takes only .5s or less. I don't think the real issue is in the code or query.

Comment: @hindmost: it would be the best thing but for now I can't, my client doesn't want it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using ob start with ob_gzhandler before outputting the result in your ajax script. This will compress your output and reduce render time.

ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

Read manual entry here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

So my php code would be

```
<?php

//get all processing done.assuming $json_result holds output.
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
echo $json_result;
ob_end_flush();
exit;
?>
```

Make sure that nothing is output to buffer in your script before hand like custom headers or any other prints.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. Ok not exactly: it works, but then the file download lasts even more (5-10sec more). So probably for the server configuration in this case it's not the right solution. I've just asked the admins to activate mod_deflate: I'll try straight htaccess way. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Stratboy - Strange. I have had 3Megs HTML output to an ajax reduced over to 270Kb. Shaves off loads of time. For e.g. I have reduced latency on a local server from 17 seconds to 4 seconds in certain scenarios. Use Fiddler to see the changes of a simple print and the ob_start('ob_gzhandler') and see timings and size reduction
Just the saving over the transport layer should decrease response time. Browser decompress the data on the fly and then render. Maybe your JSON handling can be tweaked too.